# Why am I not catching my Zod error even though I have 'express-async-errors' installed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I'm trying to develop this API but when i try to set a global error controller mediated by Zod it simply does not work. IT seems like it is not event calling my global error handle dispite using express-async-errors'.

This is my error managemet file:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { ZodError } from "zod";

class AppError extends Error {
  statusCode: number;

  constructor(message: string, statusCode: number = 400) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}

const handleErrors = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('The error handler have been called');
  
  if(err instanceof AppError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({message: err.message})
  }
  
  if (err instanceof ZodError) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: err.flatten().fieldErrors, okok:'okok' });
  }  

  return res.status(500).json({message: 'Intesdarnal server error'})
}

export { AppError, handleErrors };
```

These are my Zod schemas:

```
import { z } from "zod"

const moviesSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    name: z.string().max(50),
    description: z.string().optional().nullish(),
    duration: z.number(),
    price: z.number()
})


const moviesRequestSchema = moviesSchema.omit({id: true})

export {moviesRequestSchema, moviesSchema}
```

This is the middleware i developed:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express"
import {  ZodTypeAny } from "zod"

const checkIfCreateDataIsValid = (schema: ZodTypeAny) => (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>  {
    const validatedDate = schema.parse(req.body)
    req.body = validatedDate

    return next()
}


export default checkIfCreateDataIsValid
```

these are the routes.

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { createMoviesController } from "../controllers/movies.controller";
import checkIfCreateDataIsValid from "../middlewares/checkIfCreateDataIsValid.middleware";
import { moviesRequestSchema } from "../schemas/movies.schemas";

const moviesRoutes: Router = Router()

moviesRoutes.post('', checkIfCreateDataIsValid(moviesRequestSchema), createMoviesController)

export default moviesRoutes
```

and my app.ts:

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import "express-async-errors"
import express, { Application } from "express";
import { handleErrors } from "./errors";
import moviesRoutes from "./routes/movies.routes";


const app: Application = express()

app.use(handleErrors)
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/movies', moviesRoutes)

export default app
```

So, despite calling 'handleErrors' in my app.ts file and having express-async-errors installed. It seems like my middleware, for some reasong is not working. It is not event printing "The error handler have been called" when i send a post request with a missing parameter. Instead of showing me a zod error. It is returnig this:

`ZodError: [ { "code": "invalid_type", "expected": "number", "received": "string", "path": [ "price" ], "message": "Expected number, received string" } ] at Object.get error [as error] (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\zod\lib\types.js:43:31) at ZodObject.parse (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\zod\lib\types.js:141:22) at C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\src\middlewares\checkIfCreateDataIsValid.middleware.ts:5:34 at newFn (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express-async-errors\index.js:16:20) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at next (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13) at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3) at newFn (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express-async-errors\index.js:16:20) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) at C:\Users\arauj\Downloads\projetos\m4-movies-typeorm-H3isenberg8\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15`

I literally tried everything i could possibly think. I'm stuck here for hours

Answer (score 0):

> The order of middleware loading is important: middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.

The express error handler application-level middleware should be added after all routes.

E.g.

`app.ts`:

```
import "express-async-errors"
import express from "express";
import { AppError, handleErrors } from "./errors";


const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/movies', async (req, res) => {
  throw new AppError('test')
})
// order matters
app.use(handleErrors);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started'))
```

`errors.ts`:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

class AppError extends Error {
  statusCode: number;

  constructor(message: string, statusCode: number = 400) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }
}

const handleErrors = (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log('The error handler have been called');

  if (err instanceof AppError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.message })
  }

  return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Intesdarnal server error' })
}

export { AppError, handleErrors };
```

Access the `http://localhost:3000/movies` endpoint, the logs of the server:

```bash
Server started
The error handler have been called
```